# Way to Remove Invite Limit on FBML Multi-Friend Selector

Tags: facebook, fbml

I tried to look through various resources before posting here, but was having a surprisingly difficult time finding an answer to my question. Sorry in advance if I overlooked it.

I'm currently trying to add the FBML Multi-Friend Selector to my Facebook page. It has a limit on the number of friends you can invite at a time ("Add up to 20 of your friends by clicking on their pictures below"). From what I've looked through it sounds like 20 is the max number of friends a user can invite, but then looking at Mint's page, they have a 22 max invite (http://www.facebook.com/mint?ref=ts)

I thought it might be based on number of page fans, as Mint has 56,000, but that doesn't seem to be the case as this page only has 256 fans and have a max of 26 friend invites (http://www.facebook.com/tivix?v=app_106437999388442).

Therefore, I don't really understand how this system works. Is there a way for me to increase to 26? Unlimited?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Those limits are there for a reason. If your app plays nice and users get value out of it, those limits might go up.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to increase to 26? Unlimited?

As Yuliy says, those limits are there for a reason. That's not to say that you're a spammer, but Facebook doesn't know that.

Facebook don't publicise exactly how they determine your daily invite allocation, but it's likely to do with the proportion of invites that are accepted compared to those that are ignored or blocked.

Keep an eye on your statistics, particularly [your allocations](http://www.facebook.com/business/insights/app.php?id=106437999388442&tab=allocations). (This link will only work for Tivix developers.)

If the quality of your invites is low, your daily limit will be low. Maybe instead of trying to increase the quantity of invites, you should be focusing on the quality. (Sorry for being preachy!) Having more accepted invites will be better for you as well as for those who receive them.

Comment: Tom, 

Thanks for the response. So you're saying that the number of invites changes not based on the Fan page, but on the user who is interacting with the Fan page? 

The main thing that confuses me about this is that users can still just go over to "suggest to friends" on the sidebar and select all of their friends, whether it's 26 or 800. That's why the spam factor didn't seem like the problem to me. 

Anyway, I'm definitely not a spammer ;) I never send invites to anything. 

Thanks again, Tom. 

David

Comment: Hi David, there's an important distinction to make here. Apps have allocations. Pages don't. It gets confusing because each app has a page and each page can have apps on it. The "suggest to friends" will always suggest the page rather than the app.